Rebase sub branch from main after main got a squashed merge
This is probably a very common scenario but to the best of my efforts I couldn't find any proper answer on it using Google search or use of an LLM chatbot.
This is a team project, I was developing on my sub branch called "devel". I did 6 commits, finally reached a stage where I can push to production so I pushed my changes. On the main branch, using Gitlab's GUI, I created a squashed merge request.
I continued developing on the same branch locally, did a fix, pushed it, created another merge request but Gitlab blocked the merge with this:

So I pulled origin main, tried ff which fails, then tried rebase, merge and finally cherry pick but the all of them want to do 6 stages of rebase/merge/cherry-pick!!! This is totally unexpected. How do I make it understand to not apply those squashed merges from main to my devel branch? Do I have to delete the devel branch at this point and create a new branch to continue with my development? I'd like to have my commit history though.
So my question is how to resolve the Gitlab error and simply make a proper merge request to apply the last commit on devel branch to main branch.

"I created a squashed merge request." and "I'd like to have my commit history though." don't go together. Squashing creates a single new commit without the history, you can't have squash merges while keeping the history.

@knittl I meant keep history on the devel branch. So if need be we can refer to that, but somehow to keep main clean they like to squash commits!

But how would you know which commits of the devel branch were squashed into which commits on main? This whole approach feels error-prone. You can always run git log --first-parent main to see only the merge commits.

I see, I now recall GitLens showed my initial devel commits above the squash merge, which means as you said we can't figure out which commits were squashed. The command is very useful btw, Thanks. @knittl

Avoid squash merging if possible. As you found out, it mostly causes headaches. But all is not lost.
Let's say you start with the following history graph, 2 commits only reachable from main and 4 commits on your devel branch:
A-B-C-D             < main
   \
    E-F-G-H         < devel

Next you create a merge request and squash merge. This gives you a new commit, that I call S (short for "squash"). It contains all changes from commits E, F, G, and H.
A-B-C-D-S           < main
   \
    E-F-G-H         < devel

Then you keep working on your branch and add a few more commits:
A-B-C-D-S           < main
   \
    E-F-G-H-I-J-K   < devel

You cannot (squash) merge that again, because the changes have already been partially applied to main. Attempting a simple rebase will also fail because S contains the changes of E (and F and G and H), so E cannot be applied again – that would be like applying E on top of H.
But you can help Git by telling it what the old upstream was:
git rebase --onto main H devel

This command will take the commit range H..devel (i.e. I, J, K) and apply them on top of main. This should give fewer conflicts and avoids re-applying patches that already exist upstream. History after the rebase:
A-B-C-D-S           < main
   \     \
    \     I'-J'-K'  < devel
     \
      E-F-G-H-I-J-K



I continued developing on the same branch locally

That was your mistake. You should never do that. Specifically, once you have done a squashed merge request from a branch, you should abandon (delete) that branch. The reason is that a squashed merge is not a merge, so the commits that you "merged" are all new since the merge-base (the point where you created devel); they are not the same as the six commits that are still sitting there in your branch. Therefore they can conflict with things you've done as you've continued work on your branch — as you've now discovered.
The correct approach is to abandon this branch. Fetch, and make a new branch at the end of origin/main (the main branch as it now stands). Enact your new changes on top of that. Now you will have something that can be merged cleanly.
